# SQL: Search for duplicate rows even though they might not be exact duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to search for some duplicate records in a database, these duplicate were entered by an end user. As they were entered by an end user (presumably different people) the records are slightly different. The only thing I can possibly search on would be the company name, which as you may have guessed could potentially be worded differently. Example:

```
Id    Code    Name
1     A001    Company A LTD
2     A002    Company A Limited
3     A003    Co. A LTD
```

All 3 records are for the same company just different people may have entered these records so they have different wordings for the company name. So what I am trying to do is make it easier from a support standpoint, I want to find these records for a company with a duplicate and just remove it but as you can imagine its difficult to search on this as the names could be different.

I was thinking get the first letter and the second word of the company name using a Like statement.

```
Where Name Like 'C%A%'
```

But surely there must be a better way to do this.

Comment: Not by my machine right now - have a look at fuzzy matching

Comment: Specifically look for SOUNDEX and DIFFERENCE()

Comment: We've had these issues for many years. We even suggest names to users when they are typing in a customers name - they will still enter duplicates. SoundEx won't work very well with differences like  "Ltd" and "Limited". The only way is to educate the users!

Comment: @navigator Whilst that is true, educating users takes time, the op clearly needs to do something now. You could create a lookup table or something like that to take care of known abbreviations and then apply soundex to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `SOUNDEX()` and `DIFFERENCE()`:

[Using SOUNDEX and DIFFERENCE to Standardize Data in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2159/using-soundex-and-difference-to-standardize-data-in-sql-server/)

> SOUNDEX converts an alphanumeric string to a four-character code that
>   is based on how the string sounds when spoken. The first character of
>   the code is the first character of character_expression, converted to
>   upper case. The second through fourth characters of the code are
>   numbers that represent the letters in the expression. The letters A,
>   E, I, O, U, H, W, and Y are ignored unless they are the first letter
>   of the string. Zeroes are added at the end if necessary to produce a
>   four-character code. For more information about the SOUNDEX code, see
>   The Soundex Indexing System.
>
> SOUNDEX codes from different strings can be compared to see how
>   similar the strings sound when spoken. The DIFFERENCE function
>   performs a SOUNDEX on two strings, and returns an integer that
>   represents how similar the SOUNDEX codes are for those strings.
>
> SOUNDEX is collation sensitive. String functions can be nested.

Taken from [MSDN - SOUNDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187384.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the help.This seems to work for most cases but there are a few that will return more than 2 results or just return anything. As this is something that we will most likely be asked by the customer to do, its fine this way as we can just modify the code as we need to. I was hoping that it could be done for us so they could just do it themselves with a program I have written to call the stored procedure, but from all the answers it looks like it may be too time consuming to actually get it perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an SQL question actually. You are looking for a *rule* to apply instead, an algorithm.

From your example you could work with a list of synonymes ('Company' = 'Co.', 'Limited' = 'LTD'). Then you'd replace all 'Company' with 'Co.', all 'Limited' with 'LTD', etc. You would then compare the result strings, possibly case insensitive.

But that still wouldn't find 'A Limited' or 'A'. So maybe better remove all that is not the actual name (A in your example)? But that may cause false positives.

And then there may be typos 'Sdidas' ainstead of 'Adidas' becase the S is next to the A on the keyboard or 'didas' because the A key was not pressed hard enough :-(

It is up to you how hard or soft an algorithm you apply. One rule may get you too many "duplicates" that are none, and another not all of the actually existing duplicates.

Make up your mind what you actually want to consider a duplicate. There porbably is no "perfect" solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Full Text Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx). It can take care of things like "ltd." and "limited" or "co." and "company" through configurable thesaurus but ultimately, that would still be a manual job going through records one-by-one, checking top ranking matches and deciding which one to keep.

Answer (score 0):

As this is not really solvable by mere technical comparisions, you may want to go a completely different route.

It may be the case that all companies in your database could be identified by some business ID. One example would be the global location number GLN, or maybe a US registration number (or wherever they are located). So you could introduce this number in the tabe and then ask the people maintaining the data (i.e. those who enter the companies) to add those numbers. Then at last simply search for duplicate IDs.

(Your database is obviously based on technical IDs. In a database with natural keys you would have looked for something that uniquely identifies a Company in the first place, such as the GLN, in order to build the table. So using natural keys is often more work when setting up a database, but pays off later, as in your example where you simply couldn't have got any duplicates :-)